# Duplicate Super Administrator

Tags: administrator, group-policy, windows-vista

Is there a way to duplicate the Super Administrator account on Vista?

Please don't ask why I want to know or suggest alternatives

I would like just a simple yes or no with an explanation

***To clarify, I mean the hidden administrator account called Administrator (The account used to open executables when you right click and click "Run as Administrator") when I say "Super Administrator"***

Comment: What is the "Super Administrator"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can create any user account and add it to the administrator group.  Boom.

The "Run as Administrator" **does not** run the process under the "Super" Administrator. But rather it elevates the privileges of your current account to *admin priv*.

I'd suggest you read how UAC works.

The hidden "Super" Admin account has no more priviledges than any other account that is part of the Admin group.  As an example, the default owner of a file is the creator. Notice when you create files as the "Super" admin account, the file ownership is set to the Admin "group".

And you cannot take away permissions from Builtin groups, like the Admin.

The only real privilege the Builtin Admin account has is it is automatically enabled during Windows Recovery/Safe mode if all other Admin accounts are disabled.